# Python in-place swapping

Tags: python

The following code block does not work.

```
a = [2,1,3]
i = 1
a[i], a[a[i]-1] = a[a[i]-1], a[i]
```

Whereas this does.

```
a = [2,1,3]
i = 1
j = a[i]-1
a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
```

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left side of the equals is assigned from left to right, and each term is only evaluated as it's reached. This means that:

```
a[i], a[a[i]-1] = a[a[i]-1], a[i]
```

is equivalent to:

```
tmp = a[a[i]-1], a[i]
a[i] = tmp[0]       # Changes a[i]
a[a[i]-1] = tmp[1]  # USES new a[i] to determine assignment index!!!
```

which makes it clear that the assignment to `a[i]` finishes, then the *new* value of `a[i]` is used to compute the index of the second assignment.

Your working code works because it caches the *old* value of `a[i]`, so reassigning `a[i]` doesn't change where the second value goes; the equivalent code there making that clear:

```
j = a[i]-1           # Caches old a[i]
tmp = a[j], a[i]
a[i] = tmp[0]        # Changes a[i]
a[j] = tmp[1]        # Changes using original a[i] as intended
```